# Find stock with highest variance and swap it with first column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, variance

I have a dataframe containing m series of stock prices for different companies like the one below:

```
Date  Stock 1   Stock 2  Stock 3 ...  Stock m
1      100       200      300    ...   500
2      500       300      200    ...   100
:       :         :        :     ...    :
n      200       300      400    ...   100
```

What I need to do is find out which of the m stocks has the highest *variance* and then swap it with the entries of `Stock 1`. Assume that in the above example `Stock 3` is the one with the highest variance, the final output should then be:

```
Date  Stock 3   Stock 2  Stock 1 ...  Stock m
1      300       200      100    ...   500
2      200       300      500    ...   100
:       :         :        :     ...    :
n      400       300      200    ...   100
```

In order to find the column with highest variance I tried computing:

```
print(max(df.var()))
```

However, this only yields the amount of variance without printing the stock ticker. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.insert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for inserting column at the specified position after you get the locations from [`.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and [`Index.get_loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
col = df.set_index('Date').var().idxmax()   # get column name of max var

from_pos = df.columns.get_loc(col)          # get location of column with max var

stock1_col = df.columns[1]                  # get column name of first stock
stock1 = df.pop(stock1_col)                 # take out column of first stock

df.insert(1, col, df.pop(col))         # insert column of max var to the original position of first stock
df.insert(from_pos, stock1_col, stock1)      # insert first stock to the original position of column with max var
```

**Result:**

(`Stock m` is the column with max variance in the sample data)

```
print(col)

'Stock m'



print(df)

  Date  Stock m  Stock 2  Stock 3  Stock 1
0    1      500      200      300      100
1    2      100      300      200      500
2    n      100      300      400      200
```

Comment: That is very nice thanks! However, what if I do not know the name of Stock 1? Or better, what if I need to automate this process over many datasets and I need to bring the highest variance stock to the first column after "Date" without knowing the specific stock ticker?

Comment: @BraydenClarkson  See my edit above for modified code without needing to know the stock name of `Stock 1`.  We assume it is always in column 1 (column 0 is the `Date`).   Yes, actually, I think you don't need to swap the first stock to the original position of highest variance stock unless there is real necessity on this.   In this case, the codes can be simplified too.  You only need the first line of code and the second last line only.

Comment: Thanks it works! I have tried to loop this over several datasets: `highest_variance=[]
dataset_list=[]
for element in dataframe_list:
    highest_variance_columns=element.set_index('Date').var().idxmax()
    highest_variance.append(highest_variance_columns)
for element, column in zip(dataframe_list, highest_variance):
    new_list=element.insert(1, highest_variance, element.pop(highest_variance))
    dataset_list.append(new_list)` , where `dataframe_list` is the list of datasets. This returns an error saying that the columns are not in index. Do you know what this means?

Comment: @BraydenClarkson  Just by looking at the codes, I guess that the error was caused by the statement `element.pop(highest_variance)`   Since, in the first loop, you have put all columns of all dataframes in `dataframe_list` into the list `highest_variance`.  However, the `pop` statement` is only for working with one column at a time.  Not only that it can't handle multiple columns, it also can't handle columns in other dataframe.  You have to revise your looping logics.

Comment: @BraydenClarkson  You can try amend the looping logics.  If you still can't solve it, I would suggest you provide more information in a  new question.   I will also try to answer your new question if I see it.  In the meantime, please also upvote my answer in this question by clicking the up arrow ▲  (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)). ,

Comment: @BraydenClarkson   If you take the simplified approach to only put the column of highest variance to the first column after `Date`, you can try this code:  `dataset_list=[] 
for df in dataframe_list:     
    col = df.set_index('Date').var().idxmax()   # get column name of max var
    df.insert(1, col, df.pop(col))         # insert column of max var to the original position of first stock
    dataset_list.append(df)
`